# Canon auto ftp upload

Tags: software, publishing

Are there any Canon or Nikon camera models other than the Canon EOS 5D Mark IV that can upload to ftp automatically after a photo is taken?

We are trying to build a custom workflow. Currently we are doing it with an attached laptop, but it would be nice to have portability.

Comment: Have you looked at things like eyefi?

Comment: I did. eyefi is almost dead, they licensed their technology to Toshiba and probably pulling out of the market. We even programmed Toshiba's flash air (patented eyefi tech), but its wi-fi capabilities suck, constantly dropping connection.

Comment: I don't use wifi stuff for my own, but I'm a programmer with transfer file stuff & co. Can wifi-addapters on cameras send the photos automatically into a folder on e.g. a smartphone? if yes, you could run a tool that automatically moves the files from this folder onto a ftp. so it would be mobile, because a smartphone or tablet is small and you have one anyway. and you can adapt other cameras provided that there is a compatible adapter that can move files into a folder on the mobile device.

Comment: Why is this tagged "nikon"?

Comment: Is 'ftp' as the transfer protocol a requirement?

Comment: This seems like an [x→y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you are ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: @mattdm I believe the question is "Any other camera than the 5D that can do it?" and the Canon and Nikon tag is to say "of Canon and Nikon's models", basically excluding Sony, Olympus etc.

Comment: Tags should be used to categorize, not to add supplemental information.

Comment: @MichaelClark ftp is not a requirement, but we need to control the process for the uploaded photos, so solutions like image gateway, social media uploads, etc are out of question.

Comment: @user75439 Where do you want the photos to wind up? How far is that server from the shooting location? Basically we already have existing questions for scenarios where the intended host device is on a local network accessible by the camera. I think we also have existing questions for when the intended host is not on a LAN accessible by the camera. What is it you want to do that leads you to think ftp is the answer?

Comment: In other words, you'll probably have better luck here if you explain what it is you want to do (e.g.automatically transfer images wired?/wirelessly? from a camera to a machine down the hall or, alternately,  to a machine across the country) rather than asking which cameras can "do" what you think the solution might be.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any Canon or Nikon camera models other than the Canon EOS 5D Mark IV that can upload to ftp automatically after a photo is taken?
>
> We are trying to build a custom workflow. Currently we are doing it with an attached laptop, but it would be nice to have portability.

[Magic Lantern has FTP](https://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=11053.0) capabilities for Canon EOS 6D.

The website [NikonHacker](https://nikonhacker.com/wiki/Main_Page#Wi-Fi) has less developed firmware for Nikon and suggests [qDSLRDashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/) where an Android, iOS, or Windows application can control some of the camera's features; since source code is available you can make suitable modifications. A cellphone will be more portable than the laptop and can offer extremely fast uploads using LTE.

There's an APP on Play Store called "[Camera Upload to FTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kdongsuk.CameraUploader&hl=en)", while originally intended to transfer the phone's camera's photos you can change the folder; thus enabling automatic EyeFi transfers to be trampolined. Further searching along those lines is bound to turn up more options.